# Adding pages to tcpdf document genrated from dynamic html

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have generated a pdf, from dynamic html, using tcpdf. Now I want to add pages after some rows.

I tried using `page-break-after:always` but it has not worked for `<tr>`

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that won't work because of the nature of tables; there's no place to *put* something "after" a `<tr>`.  I recommend embedding one of these at the end of the last `<td>` in the row you want to break after:

```
<br pagebreak="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks chaos but it wont work for my pdf generation. I dont know why? Actually i have huge amount data to print using tcpdf. When same code executed for less amount of data proper pdf is generated. But if data is large it generate blank pdf with header. is any help for it? Thanks in advance